# Is it normal for the vaccination site to hurt?

Tags: pain, vaccination

I just received a vaccination today at around 9:00 in the morning, and it is still hurting really bad now at 8:40 in the evening. Is this normal?

Comment: What type of  vaccination was it and where was it administered?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's unclear from the question what vaccination this was, I looked up two likely cases: the flu vaccine, and the DTaP booster, because these are vaccines regularly given to adults.

**Influenza vaccine**

The flu vaccine can cause soreness, redness, and swelling at the spot where the vaccination was given. If the pain is more than mild, or lasts longer than a day, ask your doctor.

**DTaP, or Tdap**

Pain at the injection site occurs in 2 out of 3 adult patients. Severe pain is rare, and should be discussed with a doctor.

A rather comprehensive overview of vaccine side effects can be [found at the CDC website](http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vac-gen/side-effects.htm#tdap). Soreness and mild pain is a side effect of many, but anything severe or lasting more than 1 to 2 days should be discussed with a doctor.